# Tag cloud using php and mysql - how to link a new page using the mysql column name

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, tags, cloud

I am going to word this to the best of my ability. I have added links to the pages I need help with and their are instructions on there as well. I am new to php and need help please, thank you.

```
P.S. 
I would like to keep the code I have unless you have a better one.
```

**MY QUESTION** --- I have created buttons with words from my database table. What I need to know is **how to add a link button to the word you click on** and this link will open up my articlestagresults.php page and show the word that was selected as well as list the articles according to the word they selected from the tag cloud. Please look at my two web pages and see what I am trying to do.
Here are my two pages with notes in them to better show what I mean.
    https://livinghisword.org/articlestagresults.php ---- 
    https://livinghisword.org/articlestagcloud.php 
    enter code here
     **THIS IS THE CODE FOR articlestagcloud.php --- below**

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT word FROM articles GROUP BY word ORDER BY word ASC");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
$word = $row['word'];

ksort($word);

echo "<div class='cloudbox tag'>$word</div>";
}
```

Thank you very much for all the help coming!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap the word in anchor tag like this

```
echo "<div class='cloudbox tag'><a href = 'articlestagresults.php?word=" . $word . "'> " . $word . "</a></div>";
```

In **articlestagresults.php**, You can simply get the word by `print_r($_GET['word']);` This will give you the selected word from the previous page.

**articlestagresults.php**

```
$word = $_GET['word'];
$sql = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE word = '$word'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    print_r($row);// It will contain the row data
    //SHOW the HTML
}
```

Comment: @Jennifer Glad i could help.

Comment: This is great it is now linked and shows the word on the new page. ------ I'm almost there because of your help. Can you please show me how to list all the post based upon that word in articlestagresults.php. I am not sure how to add php code and list all post based upon what word they selected. Any help would be great! Thank you :)

Comment: @Jennifer Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: Yes I am up and running, you can check it out. Same location https://livinghisword.org/articlestagresults.php and my tags are located on https://livinghisword.org/articles.php --------------------- THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!! I could have not done this without your help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple javascript function for that, such as:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function bindEvents(){
        var col=document.querySelectorAll('div.cloudbox');
        if( col ){
            for( var n in col ){
                if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
                    col[n].addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        location.href='/articlestagresults.php?word='+this.innerHTML;
                    }.bind( col[ n ] ), false );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, false );
</script>
```

That should append the `word=value` string to the querystring - so your sql would use the value of `$_GET['word']` to process the request.

There are several ways you could do this - rather than using GET you could submit a form using POST which would keep the url in the browser as `https://livinghisword.org/articlestagresults.php`